# Connection Pool issue while accessing our Web application

Tags: java, database, oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

So From last 2 year our application was running successfully without any issue butLast 2 months below issue occurs 4-5 times

**Issue:**

```
 java.lang.Exception5386:2255:fetch database values:Exception while 
 fetching database values .Weblogic.common.resourcepll.ResourceLimitException:
 No Resources Commonly available in pool "data_source" to 
 allocate to application please increase size of the pool and retry
```

Techonology :java 
Backend:Oracle
Server: Weblogic12c
Maximum user access this application : 2
Maximum pool capacity in connection pool : 15

We want to replicate this issue in our development environment, 
 1. How can we do this ?
 2. What will be possible 'cause?
 3. What will be the possible souln

Can anybody help ?

Comment: Is there a connection resource that isn't being closed correctly somewhere? I assume you haven't changed anything recently though? no new code?

Comment: what is the tech stack for persistence?

Answer (score 0):

1. How can we do this ?:
    Configure an Application Pool to Recycle at a Scheduled Time every day
2. What will be possible 'cause?
   : application connection is not closing properly
   Or Session is not  closing properly
3. What will be the possible souln:

   Configure an Application Pool to Recycle at a Scheduled Time every day
      restart application pool at a Scheduled Time every day